# Form not going inside function it keeps ignoring the function on ```onSubmit``` and do as it do by default in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, onsubmit

I want to submit the form to Node.js, but when ever I press the submit button the page reloads, so I `console.log()` to make sure it's really going inside that function, but it did not work it did not log in the console and I tried to do a `alert` but it also not working, and nothing working even the name of the function in `onSubmit` listener is correct.

Here is the code (the full code is bit big and it can create problem in understanding the code so I am giving just the main form code and the `onSubmit` listener function).

Functions:

```
const AddProducts = async (e) => {
    alert('asdf');
    e.preventDefault();
}

const editTheProduct = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

The form code:

```
<form method='POST' onSubmit={props.addOrEdit === 'ADD' ? AddProducts : editTheProduct} className='AdminProductEdit'>

  <div className='LoginInputs'>
     <input type='text' name='name' required value={props.addOrEdit === 'ADD' ? newProduct.name : ''} onChange={handleInput} />
     <span className="LoginInputSpan">Product Name</span>
  </div>

  <div className='LoginInputs'>
      <input type='text' name='price' required value={props.addOrEdit === 'ADD' ? newProduct.price : ''} onChange={handleInput} />
      <span className="LoginInputSpan">Price</span>
  </div>

  <div className='LoginInputs' style={{ padding: '0', border: 'none', height: 'auto' }}>
    <textarea placeholder='Description' />
  </div>

  <div className="LoginBtn">
      <button type="submit" style={{ width: '200px' }}>SAVE CHANGES</button> // the Submit button
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where are you defining these functions -- and why not make the onSubmit a prop passed down depending on if it is being added or edited?

Comment: also in re-reading the code I don't think you can use async functions as event listeners.

Comment: @Jhecht I used it like in other functions also because I will use fetch API to send data to node.js and for that i need to use async, I used async in all other functions like this all worked fine but this one giving these types of issues

Comment: i even tried to do it like `<form method='POST' onSubmit={(event) => { event.preventDefault() }} >` still it not even stop the page by reloading

Answer (score 1):

this is `j|tsx` it's not vue so it's pretty annoying you need to make it clear it's a function for the compiler to work correctly:

```
<form method='POST' onSubmit={event => props.addOrEdit === 'ADD' ? AddProducts(event) : editTheProduct(event)} className='AdminProductEdit'>
```

Comment: it's still reloading the page and says ```cannot POST/   admin```  and it is still not going inside the function : (

Answer (score 1):

Write the prevent default as the first line of form and it should work

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (props.addOrEdit === "ADD") {
         AddProducts();
      } else {
         editTheProduct();
      }
 }}
 className="AdminProductEdit">
```

Another thing is make sure that there are no other buttons who have type as submit or button with no type at all. Make sure to give `type=button` explicitly for normal buttons within the form

Answer (score 1):

First check the `props` have valid data by,

```
<form method='POST' onSubmit={'ADD'=== 'ADD' ? AddProducts : editTheProduct} className='AdminProductEdit'>
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked as when I separately add the eventListner to the form like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const AdminProductEdit = document.querySelector('.AdminProductEdit');
    AdminProductEdit.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      props.addOrEdit === 'ADD' ? AddProducts(e) : editTheProduct(e)
    })
  }, [])
```

and remove the `onSubmit``` listener from the form like this

```
 <form method='POST' className='AdminProductEdit'>
```